# Ajax url is not responding after the data saved successfully in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on the live project of Ruby on rails. I have a pipeline section when I created new pipeline each time I stored data in a database though  hit the Ajax URL but now the issue is ajax url is not responding but data  successfully storing in database

**Ajax Url:**

```
url: '/new_pipelines'
type: 'Post'
dataType: 'json'
data: {pipeline:{pipelinegraphtype:pipelinegraphtype, name:tags_or_pipeline_name, published:"0", scheduler_id:"22", state:"prepared"},pipelinegraphname:pipelinegraphtype}
success: (data) ->
  console.log('Request 155 success')
error: () ->
  console.log('Request 155 fail')
```

**Create Method:**

```
def create
  @pipeline = current_user.pipelines.new params[:pipeline]
  if @pipeline.save
    @pipeline.save
    render json: @pipeline
  else
    render new
  end
end
```

Route:

```
match '/new_pipelines' => 'new_pipelines#create'
```

Comment: Can you try sending status with your render like `render json: @pipeline, status: :ok`. I think that should fix your problem

Comment: @MoizMansur Thankyou for your reply but it`s not working.

Comment: try `render json: {:pipeline => @pipeline}` in your controller

Comment: What is being displayed in your terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
def create
  @pipeline = current_user.pipelines.new params[:pipeline]
  if @pipeline.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render json: @pipeline}
    end
  else
    render new
  end
end


$.ajax({
url: '/new_pipelines'
type: 'POST'
dataType: 'json'
data: {pipeline:{pipelinegraphtype:pipelinegraphtype, name:tags_or_pipeline_name, published:"0", scheduler_id:"22", state:"prepared"},pipelinegraphname:pipelinegraphtype}
success: (data) ->
  console.log('Request 155 success')
error: () ->
  console.log('Request 155 fail')
});
```

Comment: are you sure there is nothing printed in console. I guess you should get `Request 155 success`

Comment: Yes, I am sure nothing printed in the console. It`s an issue URL not responding

Comment: what is your controller name?

Comment: This is my controller name : NewPipelinesController